# How to create layout for piano

Tags: android, layout

I am working on piano app and I am facing some problems with the layout creation. I want to create a layout like below:

[image]

But I am able to create only this

[image]

Now I want to add all the black buttons but problem is that I am not able to add view above those buttons. How can I do this? My current layout code is below, please suggest me how can I achieve this. Now I am able to click all the buttons, once I add all the buttons then each button should be clickable.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:weightSum="1.5" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/bw1"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".1"
            android:background="@drawable/blacknew" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/bw2"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".1"
            android:background="@drawable/blacknew" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/bw3"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".1"
            android:background="@drawable/blacknew" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/bw4"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".1"
            android:background="@drawable/blacknew" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/bw5"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".1"
            android:background="@drawable/blacknew" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/bw6"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".1"
            android:background="@drawable/blacknew" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/bw7"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".1"
            android:background="@drawable/blacknew" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/bw8"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".1"
            android:background="@drawable/blacknew" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/bw9"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".1"
            android:background="@drawable/blacknew" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/bw10"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".1"
            android:background="@drawable/blacknew" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/bw11"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".1"
            android:background="@drawable/blacknew" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/bw12"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".1"
            android:background="@drawable/blacknew" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/bw13"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".1"
            android:background="@drawable/blacknew" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/bw14"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".1"
            android:background="@drawable/blacknew" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/bw15"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".1"
            android:background="@drawable/blacknew" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would suggest drawing these white and black keys on your own. Use the View class, override draw() method and go for it. Of course you can try to use RelativeLayout, but later you'll have more problems with that (like multiple touches and slides detection).

```
class Piano extends View {
    public Piano(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    Bitmap whiteKey, blackKey;
    Paint paint = new Paint();

    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        if (whiteKey == null) {
            whiteKey = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.whiteKey);
        }
        if (blackKey == null) {
            blackKey = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.blackKey);
        }

        int keys = 10;

        // draw white keys
        for (int i = 0; i < keys; i++) {
            canvas.drawBitmap(whiteKey, i * whiteKey.getWidth(), 0, paint);
        }
        // draw black keys
        for (int i = 0; i < keys; i++) {
            if (i != 3 && i != 7) {
                canvas.drawBitmap(blackKey, i * blackKey.getWidth()+blackKey.getWidth()*0.5f, 0, paint);
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: there you go. It's quite simple. You should add some code to determine number of keys. I don't know if you want 10, 12 50 or as many as possible keys.

Comment: thanks for your guidense now i am able to create desired view with the combination of balck and white keys. i am creating piano with 15 white and 10 black keys i am totally new in case of canvas so will you please tell me how can i play different sound on each keys.

Comment: I guess you could accept the answer and add another question.

It's quite simple, you need notes recorded as mp3 for example. Then you have to detect, when someone presses the key. To do that simply check if the rectangular shape of the key contains the point under the users finger.

Comment: please share some code snippet if possible. i have all the sound byte now i want that whenever i press any key it should be highlighted and play correspond sound

Comment: your answer is awesome but can you please share a code snippet as well.

Answer (score 0):

you may get what you want by using layout containers, with this it is possible to overlay buttons and lables